# Rebar3 not "including" my non-application deps

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I have simple function:

```
do_stuff(_Whatever) ->
  jiffy:decode(<<"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}">>).
```

As you can see it depends on library jiffy. So I added it in `rebar.config`:

```
{deps, [
  {cowboy, {git, "https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy", {tag, "2.0.0-pre.1"}}},
  {jiffy, {git, "https://github.com/davisp/jiffy", {tag, "0.14.8"}}}
]}.
{relx, [{release, { myapp, "0.1.0" },
     [vizcerl,
      sasl
      ]},

    %{sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
    %{vm_args, "./config/vm.args"},

    {dev_mode, true},
    {include_erts, false},

    {extended_start_script, true}]
}.
```

But when i run `rebar3 run` and program get's do that point i get error that that function is undefined.

Edit:
I run `rebar3 tree` to check if dep is recognized and here is result:

```
└─ myapp─0.1.0 (project app)
   ├─ cowboy─2.0.0-pre.1 (git repo)
   │  ├─ cowlib─1.0.0 (git repo)
   │  └─ ranch─1.0.0 (git repo)
   └─ jiffy─0.14.8 (git repo)
```

Comment: did you run `rebar3 upgrade` first. If I am correct it will install all the necessary dependencies in the deps directory.

Comment: Sure... I have also cleaned everything. Edit: I just did rebar3 upgrade and nothing had changed.

Comment: @Pascal Also worth noting is that cowboy works and jiffy doesn't

Comment: Dumb question but what do you get if you compile it with `erlc`?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Dumb question, isn't that for compiling single files? How do I do that for whole project?

Comment: What happens if you try compiling the file containing that snippet you posted?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Nothing really,.. no console output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jiffy needs a port compiler plugin that is not part of rebar. you can configure it in your rebar.config as follows:

```
{plugins, [
    { pc, {git, "git@github.com:blt/port_compiler.git", {branch, "master"}}}
]}.
{overrides,
 [{override, jiffy, [
     {plugins, [pc]},
     {artifacts, ["priv/jiffy.so"]},
     {provider_hooks, [
         {post,
             [
             {compile, {pc, compile}},
             {clean, {pc, clean}}
             ]
          }]
      }
  ]}
]}.
```

Comment: That was part of the answer.. And i needed to add it to applications. I thought Application list was for starting... And it seems not. But after I added your part and added jiffy to apps list it seems to work or at least not crash

Comment: i believe you need to add jiffy to applications because the nif needs to be initialized. regardless, applications is for all applications you want included in your release/environment, regardless of whether they need to be started or not

Comment: It was crashing before i added that plugin. I had no idea there was need for that.